# Is it possible to change the background color of the Object Explorer and the Result Menu in SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server

Pretty much what the title says. Just started learning SQL server. I found how to 'unlock' the dark theme and how to change the fonts and sizes but i still can't change the color in the Object Explorer and the Result Menu in SQL Server Management Studio 2017. Is it possible that this is all we got till now... Cause it is hard for me to believe that there is no working full dark theme for SQL Server Management Studio 2017 or the possibility to change it manualy. Any help would be much appreciated. Also is there another IDE or editor for SQL server 2017 other than SQL Server Management Studio 2017, like there are a LOT diffirent editors for programing languages like Sublime, NotePad++, VS Code etc...

Comment: No, this is not possible *natively*. SSMS has a lot of old Windows GUI baggage that will require a ton of work to make compatible with a dark theme. You may be able to find further hacks but it won't be supported and will probably get undone with every update.

Comment: If you want a dark theme so bad, why don't you use [SQL Operations Studio](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/11/15/announcing-sql-operations-studio-for-preview/)?

Comment: i will now. Thanks for the help dude. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: please see answer suggested by member DevSam.

---

Regarding a solution from Microsoft, according to https://datamajor.net/ssms_darktheme/ and other sources
Dark theme in SSMS is incomplete and it isn't clear whether it will ever be completed and officially included.

Alternative IDEs with dark theme:

- Azure Data Studio     (by Microsoft free)
- Visual Studio Code    (by Microsoft free)
- Visual Studio Express (by Microsoft free)
- dbForge Studio        (by DevArt paid product)

Comment: how does this even answer the question??

Comment: It answers the question, it's an implied no.  That's why microsoft disabled the dark mode theme in SSMS, they haven't updated aspects of it (like the object explorer) to work with Dark Mode.  Therefore you're only options is to live with the things that don't do dark mode or switch to another tool that does do dark mode.

Comment: And if you don't need "debugging" VS Code works great for working with Sql Databases (has an explorer that works in dark mode).  And if you want something better than SSMS, use Visual Studio with it's Sql Server Database Project and SSDT Tools with all supports dark mode too.

Comment: I much prefer VSCode for doing POC scripting etc as I can create a folder and easily save/run scripts in there against mssql and it keeps a history of all the queries I've run so I can get back to them easily.

Answer (score 9):

SSMS Shades makes everything dark including object explorer and Results box https://www.sqlshades.com/

Comment: According to the site itself, this extension only works for SSMS 2019 (v18) and SSMS 2023 (v19). The question was about SSMS 2017 (v17), but it still may be helpful for other people that come across this question/answer.

Answer (score -1):

run powershell as run as adminstrator and run this code to change bg to dark mode :

```html
powershell -Command "(gc 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms.pkgundef') -replace '\[\`$RootKey\`$\\Themes\\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}\]', '//[`$RootKey`$\Themes\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}]' | Out-File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms.pkgundef'"
```

Comment: This command just enables the Dark theme option in SSMS settings and doesn't apply it. Moreover, Object Explorer and Results are still with white background.